# State represented by arrays: I get different values between adding the array and keeping a state variable with the sum of the array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an Estate react represented by two arrays, one of them is called `listLevel[]`, and is an array of `int`s, and an `int` variable states. `sum` represents the sum of all of the `listLevel[]` values. 
Sometimes, not always, when in the `render()` I show the variable state, I get a different and smaller value of the `sum` of the `listingLevel[]` array, that is, state. `sum` is missing the last value of `listingLevel[]`, instead of showing the variable state. When I calculate the `sum` of the `listLevel[]` array, the value is always correct.

```js
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.actualizar = this.invocarMetodoNivel.bind(this);

        this.state = {
          listaNivel: [],
          listaSensor: [],
          suma: 0
        };
      }
      onAddSensor = (sensorname, nivel) => {
        this.setState(state => {
          const listaSensor = state.listaSensor.concat(sensorname);
          const listaNivel = state.listaNivel.concat(Number(nivel));
          var sum = 0;
          for (var i = 0; i < this.state.listaNivel.length; i++) {
            sum = sum + this.state.listaNivel[i];

          }
          return {
            listaNivel: listaNivel,
            listaSensor: listaSensor,
            suma: sum
          };
        });
      };
    onUpdateNivel = (pos, level) => {
        this.setState(state => {

          const listaSensor = state.listaSensor;

          const list = state.listaNivel.map((item, j) => {
            if (j === pos) {
              return level;
            } else {
              return item;
            }
          });
          var sum = 0;
          for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            sum = sum + list[i];
          }
          return {
            listaNivel: list,
            listaSensor: listaSensor,
            suma: sum
          };
        });
      };
```

Comment: In `onAddSensor`, I think you want to loop through `listaNivel` and not `this.state.listaNivel`. You will be looping through the current class state instead of the updated list that you just concat'd with the new value.

Comment: Thanks, you are right!